# What does "goes on the whole" mean here?

Tags: meaning, phrases

…. the child, in mastering himself (his behaviour), ***goes on the whole*** in the same way as he
does in mastering external nature, e.g. by technical means. The Man masters himself
externally, as one of the forces of nature by means of a special cultural ‘technique of signs’.

Comment: idiom: on the whole. Terrible writing, by the way.

Comment: *on the whole* means *in general*, *all things considered*.

Comment: @Lambie - it's a translation from Russian of a work by Lev Vygotsky, a Marxist (Soviet) psychologist, who published _The Problem of the Cultural Development of the Child_  in Moscow in 1929. His main work, as you might guess, was in developmental psychology. He was virtually unknown in the West until the early 1980s. Came to be an admirer of Piaget.

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey Then, the translation is bad.

Comment: @Lambie - it's awful.

Answer (score 2):

'On the whole' is an idiom meaning 'generally' or 'mostly'. If something is true on the whole, it is true in general but may not be true in every case.

The sentence you quoted would be better if 'on the whole' were preceded and followed by parenthetical commas.

> ... the child, in mastering himself (his behaviour), goes, on the
> whole, in the same way as he does in mastering external nature, e.g. by technical means.